# LaunchD Job Failed weird reason: 2

Tags: python, json, mongodb, launchd

I've been trying to use launchD to execute a script every 24 hours, but I keep receiving an error for weird reason: 2; I understand that this means that the file was not found, but I checked and double checked to ensure that the filepath in the Program Argument is correct. The script runs fine when I execute it in the terminal. Any ideas on why this won't work?

The script simply scrapes information of newly added startups off of AngelList and sends it out via e-mail.

Below is my launchD and Python script:

```
Python: 

#!/opt/local/bin/python2.6
import urllib
import json
import datetime
import ast
import time
import smtplib
from pymongo import MongoClient
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

... #code omitted 

def find_data(): 
   client = MongoClient()
   client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
   db = client.tiger_labs
   collection = db.new_startups
   existing_names = []
   for startup in collection.find(): 
      existing_names.append(startup.get('name')) # inserts all "already-found" startups to the database

   market_tags = ["mobile health", "health care", "health care information technology", "health and wellness", "personal health"] # lists out all tags

   ... # code omitted

   text += "</html>"
   if text != "<html></html>": # sends e-mail if not empty
       nathan = "testerisgood@gmail.com"
       tigerlabs = "****@tigerlabs.co, *****@tigerlabs.co"
       msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
       msg['Subject'] = "New Startups"
       msg['From'] = nathan
       msg['To'] = tigerlabs
       part1 = MIMEText(text, 'html')
       msg.attach(part1)
       server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')  
       server.starttls()  
       server.login("testerisgood@gmail.com", "******")
       server.sendmail(nathan, tigerlabs, msg.as_string())
       server.quit()
       print "sent"
   else: # purely for testing reasons; wanted to see if launchD was executing
       server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')  
       server.starttls()  
       server.login("testerisgood@gmail.com", "*********")
       server.sendmail("testerisgood@gmail.com", "*****@princeton.edu", "Hi it worked.")
       server.quit()
       print "not_sent"

find_data()

LaunchD:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.tigerlabs.TigerLabs</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/nathanlam/Desktop/Programming_Labs/Coding/TigerLabs.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>86400</integer>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
          <key>NetworkState</key>
          <true />
    </dict>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/test.stderr</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: 2 in `/usr/include/sys/errno.h` is `ENOENT`, i.e. `no such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

In my bash script I did make every path absolute. In my LaunchAgent I just did the same!
In my LaunchAgent I used a ~ in stead of /Users/xyz . The last adjustment did the trick!